# MacBook Pro HD shows gray progress bar, bar completes and Mac turns off

Tags: macbook, boot-camp, osx-mavericks

I've MacBook Pro HD (late 2011) with Maverick and a Bootcamp partition.

Yesterday, when I turned on my Macbook it made thestarting sound, showed the Apple logo and a progress bar. The progress bar completes and then Mac turns off.

But BootCamp is working fine. I have installed MacDrive on my win-7 in bootcamp. When win-7 starts it shows me following popup: `macbook pro hd was not safely disconnected when last used, and may contain errors`.

OS X partition's data is totally accessible from Windows.

One thing that is to be mentioned that last day before problem, there was an update to Maverick was available to App Store, I started to download it. Don't know downloading was completed or not. (Just to inform)

I've tried some solutions but didn't worked for me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just add what you have tried to avoid people adding that. Have tried the following
1. Run Disk Utility by booting into OS X recovery mode
2. Safe boot
3. Reset NVRAM
4. Reinstall Mavericks

Answer (score 0):

You could boot into recovery mode and reinstall Mavericks. Don't worry it won't delete your data.